# Javascript/Angular - Prevent default action with back button on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components, pushstate

I have create a component with angular 7, which is a kind of full screen modal. The problem is that when you open this modal... on mobile devices you think that you change page... and you press the back button (mobile) to go back. So... you change page without reason. I want simply close the modal by pressing the back button. I manage to catch the back button event, but I can't prevent the default action of change the page

```
@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
onPopState(event) {
   console.log('Back button pressed');
   // 1) Code to close my custon modal
   // 2) Prevent redirect
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it...

```
window.history.forward();
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your answer after you found the solution yourself! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.